# MacbookPro14,2 Gigabit internet Speed. Is it possible?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, performance, internet, ethernet

I have MacbookPro14,2, and following is the internal ethernet spec. I was wondering if its possible to use external gigabit ethernet (found on USBc dock), and have gigabit internet. I have a gigabit lan connection. I was wondering since the USB speed is up to 480 Mbps. Or its not at all possible to get gigabit internet speed with macbook pro?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image shows the Apple T1 Controller instead of an ethernet controller. Your model Mac does not have builtin ethernet. Apple recommends a [Belkin USB-C to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJKF2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter), which is compatible with your 2017 13-inch MacBook Pro. However, you could also use a dock with Gigabit ethernet and an USB-C connection to your Mac.

Comment: But if USB link speed is 480 Mbps, can it still support Gigiabit internet?

Comment: Although I do not have a Mac with a Touch Bar, a USB link speed of 480Mb/s to the Apple T1 Controller seems like a reasonable value. However, this has nothing to do with with accessing the internet. Your Mac **does** support Gigabit internet through the use of an external device.